# Drawing a Bitmap to a Canvas with an alpha gradient

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, gradient

I'd like to draw a `Bitmap` on a `Canvas`, with a (linear) alpha gradient applied. The important point is that I don't want to overlay the image with any other color; the background (coming from the `View`s behind the `View` that I'd be drawing this `Canvas` to) should just "shine through". To illustrate, my goal would be something like this (the checkerboard pattern represents the `View` behind)

[image: linear alpha gradient]

One would think that I could do something like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ...;
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0, FROM, TO, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

but `LinearGradient`'s `FROM` and `TO` arguments here would need to be colors, not alpha values; so there's no way that I see to specify that e.g. `FROM` should be fully transparent and `TO` should be fully opaque (without applying any color overlay).

Comment: check this library https://github.com/chiuki/android-graphics-demo

Comment: @Cactus I see `LinearGradient` expects `color0` (from) and `color1` (to) to be an int. Will it allow a decimal representation of an rbga value, or does it only allow rgb, or is it expecting something else entirely? The documentation is rather unclear on what this int value is. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html

Comment: @d.j.brown: it's a 32-bit ARGB value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use a `ComposeShader`, like this:

```
class V extends View {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.chrome);
        Shader shaderA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0xffffffff, 0x00ffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Shader shaderB = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(new ComposeShader(shaderA, shaderB, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: of course you would need to change `LinearGradient` constructor params to get the desired gradient

Comment: I like this better than the one I was able to come up with, on principle. But is there also a performance benefit due to not having to create an off-screen `Canvas`?

Comment: i think it is: not only in CPU clocks but also by eaten memory connected with the creation of off-screen `Bitmap`, btw you could do what you did with `Canvas#saveLayer` (without additional `Bitmap` creation) but still i think `ComposeShader` is closer to the low-level GPU stuff

Comment: Is it possible to combine this code with Picasse / Glide? Can you plase make an example :-)?

Answer (score 6):

Based on [this answer about masking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26031133/477476), I was able to do this using a secondary off-screen canvas:

```
Bitmap backing = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
{
    Canvas offscreen = new Canvas(backing);
    offscreen.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0, 0x00000000, 0xFF000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
    offscreen.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
}
canvas.drawBitmap(backing, 0, 0, null);
```