# Android extends imageView gradient transparent vertical linear from input bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-canvas

i need to extends custom ImageView with linear gradient tranparent. like below image.my input is bitmap data from `fresco`. botton 0% opacity and top 100%. can you help me how to?

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView (or View) {
    ....
}
```

and

```
myImageView.doIt(myBitmapImageWithoutGradient);
```

thanks.

[image: my image]

**UPDATE:**

```
public class GradientImageAlpha extends View {

    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint paint;

    public GradientImageAlpha(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public GradientImageAlpha(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GradientImageAlpha(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public void inputBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;

        Shader shaderA = new LinearGradient(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0xffffffff, 0x00ffffff, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Shader shaderB = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(new ComposeShader(shaderA, shaderB, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can this trick for transparent view [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14345943/4797289)

Comment: @RasoulMiri this solution need to solid color match with background color :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395350/2252830

Comment: no problem really

Comment: @pskink [stackoverflow.com/a/40395350/2252830](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395350/2252830) this fix, but i need scaleType center Crop. what is solution? should reszie bitmap to screen?

Comment: no, make a custom `BitmapDrawable` class

Comment: @pskink can you help me. i;m noob

Comment: create a class that extends `BitmapDrawable`

Comment: @pskink instead extends `View` ?

Comment: yes, instead extends `View`

Comment: @pskink `BitmapDrawable` have not `onDraw` method and `Default constructor in android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable is deprecated`. can you write for me. thanks. i;m noob

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html and use the constructor that is not deprecated: did you see how many constructors you can use when extending `BitmapDrawable`(there are 3 non deprecated ones) ?

Comment: @pskink please see update my question

Comment: and? this is a copy of my custom `View` it does not use any `scaleType` - it draws the image in its exact size with no scaling

Comment: @pskink after call my image is zoom on display. i want scaletype centercrop `imageview` method

Comment: so make a custom `BitmapDrawable` then

Comment: @pskink `so make a custom BitmapDrawable then`. how ? :(

Comment: `class MyBitmapDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {...`

Comment: @pskink ok, after make it, how to add to xml view?

Comment: you cant add custom `Drawable` to xml - you have ti use `ImageView` api to set this `Drawable` as the content of the `ImageView` - see `ImageView` documentation

Comment: @pskink ok undrestand. `((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgeview)).setImageDrawable(new CustomDrawable(...))` ?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: what's the solution for this question? Can you please post the correct code?